# Why require declare BufRead in read line sample of rust

Tags: rust

Why we require `std::io::BufRead` in the example, without it, the 'lines' will be undefined method.

https://riptutorial.com/rust/example/4275/read-a-file-line-by-line

```
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::{BufRead, BufReader};

fn main() {
    let filename = "src/main.rs";
    // Open the file in read-only mode (ignoring errors).
    let file = File::open(filename).unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    // Read the file line by line using the lines() iterator from std::io::BufRead.
    for (index, line) in reader.lines().enumerate() {
        let line = line.unwrap(); // Ignore errors.
        // Show the line and its number.
        println!("{}. {}", index + 1, line);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I need to import a trait to use the methods it defines for a type?](/q/25273816/2189130)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the message

```
     = help: items from traits can only be used if the trait is in scope
help: the following trait is implemented but not in scope; perhaps add a `use` for it:
     |
1    | use std::io::BufRead;
```

This means that method `lines` is in trait `BufRead` and the trait is implemented for `BufReader`. But to be able to use method `lines` for `BufReader` you have to import the trait